# Android Studio onClickListener inside an OnClickListener attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have a simple app that has a button and a text view, when the button is clicked (***the error is app just crashes***) a dialog popup will show up and from the dialogpopup, there will be a text field and a button. I will enter a name in the text field and when i click the button, the text view (in the main activity) will be set to the name that i inputted (from the alertdialog).

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    EditText txt;
    TextView title;
    Button btn, btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showPopup(){
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View popup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_tab, null);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idtxt);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String theTxt = txt.getText().toString();
                title.setText(theTxt);
            }
        });

        dialogBuilder.setView(popup);
        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Error in Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.listenertest.MainActivity.showPopup(MainActivity.java:41)
        at com.example.listenertest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the popup views belong to it, you need to change:

```
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
```

to:

```
btn2 = (Button) popup.findViewById(R.id.button2);
txt = (EditText) popup.findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Button and EditText declaration as these Views are inside Your AlertDialog layout (i.e. popup in your case)

```
btn2 = (Button) popup.findViewById(R.id.button2);
txt = (EditText) popup.findViewById(R.id.idtxt);
```